# Can this Neo4J Cypher query be improved by using a WHERE clause instead of FILTER?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is running on Neo4J 2.0.0-M04. Here is the link with the data and query, http://console.neo4j.org/?id=yybtki

The objective of the query is to find books that Tom has not read from people who has read similar books to Tom.

Query with FILTER function:

```
MATCH p1:Person-[:READS]->b1:Book<-[:READS]-p2:Person-[:READS]->b2:Book
WHERE p1.name = 'Tom' AND (p1-[:READS]->b1)
WITH COLLECT(b1) AS MyBooks, COLLECT(DISTINCT b2) AS OtherBooks
RETURN FILTER(x IN OtherBooks : NOT x IN MyBooks);
```

I have managed to run the query successfully with the FILTER function but was wondering if there is a better way to do it in the WHERE clause.

Trying something like the below doesn't work.

```
MATCH p1:Person-[:READS]->b1:Book<-[:READS]-p2:Person-[:READS]->b2:Book
WHERE p1.name = 'Tom' AND NOT (p1-[:READS]->b1)
RETURN b2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty close. The trick is that p1 should not yet have read book b2 and not b1.

```
MATCH p1:Person-[:READS]->b1:Book<-[:READS]-p2:Person-[:READS]->b2:Book 
WHERE p1.name = 'Tom' AND NOT (p1-[:READS]->b2) 
RETURN b2
```

You could event improve the algorithm by ordering the books recommendations by "similarity" of p1 and p2. A very simple approach would be using the number of books read in common as measure of similarity:

```
MATCH sim=p1:Person-[:READS]->b1:Book<-[:READS]-p2:Person, p2-[:READS]->b2:Book 
WHERE p1.name = 'Tom' AND NOT (p1-[:READS]->b2) 
RETURN b2, count(sim) order by count(sim) desc
```

In your example there are 2 paths to book 5 and only one to book 3 so assuming that book 5 is the better match.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I keep thinking along the lines of using the WHERE clause as a filter based on the match results.